# Enabling PAE in Ubuntu 12.04 on Asus EEE PC 1025C

Tags: 12.04, asus, eeepc, pae

I have a EEE PC 1025C which came pre-loaded with Windows 7 Starter Edition. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit as dual-boot with no difficulties. An output of `uname -r` gave an output of `3.4.0-030400-generic`. A few weeks later, I installed a 4GB stick of RAM instead. I installed the PAE files using apt-get (`linux-generic-pae` and `linux-headers-generic-pae`). I also verified that the processor is PAE-capable by checking `/proc/cpuinfo`. However, the system still is not PAE-enabled (same output of `uname` as before). When I check my total memory using `free -m`, it says 3019, but BIOS tells me that all 4GB are there on the boot screen. What am I missing?

Comment: You need to select the pae kernel from the boot menu, and, possibly, remove the non-pae ones, so that they don't confuse you. If you don't see the menu at boot, press the Shift key after the BIOS screen.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the PAE kernel is only part of it - you also have to update grub.  Try running

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot to see if the PAE kernels show up on the grub menu.

Alternatively, you could reinstall with the 64 bit release.  I also note that 3.4.0 is not a normal kernel release for 12.04.  It should be 3.2.0-31-generic-pae

The normal generic kernels were removed from Ubuntu 12.04 some time after the initial release - the pae kernels are now the default.  Generic kernels are still used for some releases such as Lubuntu.
[image]

Comment: When kernels are installed, grub gets auto-updated. The OP claims to have the 3.4 non-pae kernel that would always be higher on the boot list then 3.2 pae ones, no matter how many times it's updated.

Answer (score 0):

The Asus Eee PC 1025C does NOT support either 64 bit processing or PAE.  The Asus Eee PC 1025C contains a $42 CPU (Intel N2600 - AKA 'Cedar Trail').  In order to keep the retail price of their netbook low (and therefore, competitive) Asus did not want to pay full price for the CPU, so it negotiated with Intel, who agreed to lower the price of the CPU. However, in return for the price reduction, Intel disabled both 64 bit computing AND PAE.

To add insult to injury, the Asus Eee PC 1025C has a sticker on its keyboard that reads: "Dual Core CPU'.  This statement is simply untrue.  It should read: "We were too cheap to pay full price for this dual core CPU, so we had Intel disable the 64 bit core, and then lied to our customers".